# JQuery Ajax POST no longer hits ServerSide asp.net Method after adding parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

Before adding any parameters I had this POST method hitting my serverside code whenever a user would set focus from one control to another. This was good but i need to pass data of the id and value. These values are being populated from what gather in my failure growl.

The issue is that I don't exactly know why it will no longer hit my serverside routine. I did look around stackoverflow a good deal for some help, i did clean up a few things but I couldnt quite pinpoint exactly where my issue is.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id;
    var value;

    $(".tpControl").blur(function () {

        id = this.id;
        value = $(this).val();

        var postdata = { identifier: id, controltext: value };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "TimePoints.aspx/ClientSideSave",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: postdata,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
                    OnSuccess(msg.d);
                } else {
                    OnSuccess(msg);
                }
            },
            error: OnFailure
        });
    });

    function OnSuccess(result) {
        $.growlUI('AutoSave Successful');
    }

    function OnFailure(result) {
        $.growlUI("ID: " + id, "Answer: " + value);
    }
});
```

My Server side is pretty simple

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void ClientSideSave(string identifier, string controltext)
    {
       //Bunch of code, shouldn't affect anything.
    }
```

Thank you in advance. Any help would be great, im pretty new to the world of Jquery and Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but remember you are posting JSON, not form value collections.  This means [JSON strings are quoted during transport](http://www.json.org/) and in your example, will be quoted on the backend, probably not what you really want:

```
var postdata = "{ 'identifier': 'id', 'controltext': 'value' }";
```

[3 mistakes to avoid when using jQuery with ASP.NET AJAX](http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/)

If you want use JSON(JavaScript **Object** Notation) the right way, then you should follow this example:

[Using complex types to make calling services less… complex](http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/)

Comment: I don't think 'id' or 'value' should be in quotes here.

Comment: I'm going to give this the gold star because this got me to where i needed to go and has some helpful links.

My exact syntax ended up being

    `$var postdata = "{ 'identifier': '" + id + "', 'controltext': '"+ value + "' }";`
Now my serverside method is being hit and passing the variable data that i need to collect. Thank you big time for the help.